# Drawing a line using d3 is not visible when all data items are the same

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a line using a code similar to the sample bellow, it's working fine except when all the data items are equal.

For instance, with the following the data I have a circle drawn but no line.

```
var data1 = [{
  "Date": "Feb 1, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 2, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 3, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 4, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 8, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 9, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 10, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 11, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}];
```

If only of the "Close" values were different than 25 the line would be visible.

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 40;
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - 4, 0]);
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %d, %Y").parse;
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("linear") // use basis for rounded
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });

function sparkline(elemId, data, lo, hi, targetPoint) {

  var point = targetPoint;

  targetPoint = data1.length - targetPoint;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.Date);
    d.close = +d.Close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.close;
  }));

  var svg = d3.select(elemId)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 2)');

  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", (point * 10) + "%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset",  (point * 10) + "%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green");

  svg.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'sparkline')
    .attr('d', line)
    .style("stroke", "url(#gradient)");

  svg.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
    .attr('cx', x(data[data.length - targetPoint].date))
    .attr('cy', y(data[data.length - targetPoint].close))
    .attr('r', 2.5);

}

var data1 = [{
  "Date": "Feb 1, 2014",
  "Close": "26"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 2, 2014",
  "Close": "27"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 3, 2014",
  "Close": "29"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 4, 2014",
  "Close": "23"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "22"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "22"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 8, 2014",
  "Close": "24"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 9, 2014",
  "Close": "29"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 10, 2014",
  "Close": "26"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 11, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}];

var targetPoint = 3;
sparkline('#spark1', data1, 24.3, 25.6, targetPoint);
```

```css
.sparkline {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="spark1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-straight)

You need to change default value of `gradientUnits` attribute

```
var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
        .attr('gradientUnits',"userSpaceOnUse")  // Add This LIne
        .attr("id", "gradient") 
        .attr("x1", "0%")
        .attr("x2", "100%");
```

check snippet

```js
var width = 400;
    var height = 40;
    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 2]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - 4, 0]);
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %d, %Y").parse;
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("linear") // use basis for rounded
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.close);
      });

    function sparkline(elemId, data, lo, hi, targetPoint) {

      var point = targetPoint;

      targetPoint = data1.length - targetPoint;

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.Date);
        d.close = +d.Close;
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.close;
      }));

      var svg = d3.select(elemId)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 2)');

      var defs = svg.append("defs");

      var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
        .attr('gradientUnits',"userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("id", "gradient")
        .attr("x1", "0%")
        .attr("x2", "100%");

      gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%")
        .attr("stop-color", "red");

      gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", (point * 10) + "%")
        .attr("stop-color", "red");

      gradient.append("stop")
        .attr("offset",  (point * 10) + "%")
        .attr("stop-color", "green");

      svg.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('class', 'sparkline')
        .attr('d', line)
        .style("stroke", "url(#gradient)");

      svg.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
        .attr('cx', x(data[data.length - targetPoint].date))
        .attr('cy', y(data[data.length - targetPoint].close))
        .attr('r', 2.5);

    }

    var data1 = [{
  "Date": "Feb 1, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 2, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 3, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 4, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 5, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 8, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 9, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 10, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}, {
  "Date": "Feb 11, 2014",
  "Close": "25"
}];

    var targetPoint = 3;
    sparkline('#spark1', data1, 24.3, 25.6, targetPoint);
```

```css
.sparkline {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='spark1'></div>
```