# Highcharts shadow from another SVG in the page not working for straight line

Tags: javascript, highcharts, shadow

I am trying to use shadow from a svg to work with highcharts. It is working if the graph is not a straight line but in case of straight line only markers are visible (not the line connecting the markers)

I have updated the fiddle on [highchart's website](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns) for glow

Fiddle to show the problem (when graph is in straight line) : 
http://jsfiddle.net/hx5Lgwyv/

working Fiddle (when graph is not a straight line):  http://jsfiddle.net/zhpbuwuf/1/

The only change I did in above fiddles is changed a point `[60.9, false]`

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how Gaussian blur is implemented, but seeing as you define a standard deviation of how much you blur, I am fairly confident that the issue is how it works. Since you are just drawing a straight line, standard deviation is 0, therefore, blur will also be 0 and no line will show.

Comment: The topic is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-straight  `filterUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'` fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e20ycs4f/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG Line with Gradient Stroke Won't Display Straight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-straight)