# How to apply an SVG filter to a straight path?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I want to make paths blur, this works for all paths but the straight ones.
However, the straight paths are not shown.

I found the question [SVG Line with Gradient Stroke Won't Display Straight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-straight) which seems to answer the question very well. However, I have not been able to change the Units such that the straight lines are displayed.

```css
    path {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 5px;
      fill: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <svg width="300" height="300">

    <filter id="blurMe">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>

    <path d= "M 100 100 L 200 100" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
    <path d= "M 200 100 L 200 200" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
    <path d= "M 200 200 L 100 200" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
    <path d= "M 100 200 L 100 100" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
    <path d= "M 100 100 L 200 200" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
    <path d= "M 200 100 L 100 200" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>

  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`. Alternatively you can group all your paths in a `<g>` element and apply the filter to the group.

```css
path {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 5px;
      fill: black;
      filter:url(#blurMe);
    }
```

```html
 <svg width="300" height="300">

    <filter id="blurMe" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>

    <path d= "M 100 100 L 200 100" />
    <path d= "M 200 100 L 200 200" />
    <path d= "M 200 200 L 100 200" />
    <path d= "M 100 200 L 100 100" />
    <path d= "M 100 100 L 200 200" />
    <path d= "M 200 100 L 100 200" />

  </svg>
```