# Chrome doesn't recognise stroke color from url on short lines

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, colors

My SVG:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-1 -1 130 130">
    <linearGradient id="line_color">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <line id="line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="url(#line_color)" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line id="dash" x1="64" x2="64" y1="0" y2="4" stroke="url(#line_color)" stroke-width="2"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="url(#line_color)" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

I have defined a color and applied it to #line, both Firefox and Chrome draw this line fine. But when I draw #dash with the same color, Firefox draws it like it should and Chrome doesn't. Circle is drawn just fine by both.

If #dash's stroke color is changed to "black", Chrome draws it.

[Firefox 79.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khSVc.png)
[Chromium 84.0.4147.135](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUboB.png)

I've noticed Chrome's behavior in Ristretto, but Telegram's desktop client and Simple Gallery app on Android seem to draw lines like Firefox.

Comment: It's not about very short lines. It's about horizontal and vertical lines. Please use `<linearGradient id="line_color" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">` Also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223636/svg-gradient-for-perfectly-horizontal-path